# Speed up debugging the conda-build tutorial

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I'm working outward from [this conda-build example](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html) to eventually build a conda package of my own. (If you try it out, note that the `meta.yaml` in the example is out of date and you need to use a different `meta.yaml`; details in [this issue](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/4164).)

The source code in this conda-build example is an existing project called click, which seems to have a very specific structure with elements like `tox.ini` and `setup.py` and `setup.cfg`. It's hard for me to find definitive guidance on Conda's requirements or expectations about the structure of the source code anywhere in the [conda-build docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/index.html), so I've just been changing one thing at a time starting from the working example and checking if it still works.

Each `conda build` command takes several minutes. It makes debugging slow and I've gotten impatient. How can I speed up `conda build` so that I can easily experiment with different inputs? There are tips to speed up conda environment solving [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance), but I'm not solving an environment; I'm building a package.

My package is pure Python, so I don't need to bother with any compiler details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `boa`, which is an add-on to `conda-build` that will use Mamba as the solver instead (much faster solves). Once installed, one uses:

```
conda mambabuild
```

instead of

```
conda build
```

Not just me, but the entire Conda Forge CI has used `boa` for several months now.